# How to find the application server process ID from oracle database

Tags: oracle, blocking

I have an application which runs on Linux, and its backend database is Oracle (12.1.0.2). Recently we faced an issue that one of the session created blocking to many other application connections. By identifying the blocking session list i figureout SID,SQl_ID,Machine etc. Further i was able to find the OSPID (OS process id of Oracle database) to kill the session from OS. But our client asked me to tell him the way to identify the session on application server (Linux), so that he can kill the session from application server instead of DB server, when ever there is similar issues in future. is there a way to find out the actual connection (OSPID) from application server instead of DB serer?

Thanks
Srinivas

Comment: `v$session.process` gives you the client OS process ID, which would be the application server's process ID. However, Oracle clients can set it to any value they want - Tomcat often sets it to 1234, for example - so you may need to configure it. Also, you haven't given us any details, but your application server probably uses session pooling, so your client process will probably be serving multiple users, and killing the process will interrupt all of them. Just FYI.

Comment: @kfinity, thank you. Yes, application uses connection pool to establish connections. Instead of "1234", Is there a way to set different "ProcessID" for each connection from application?

Comment: If you can edit the application code, you can [change the v$session identifiers by setting the Thin Client connection props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612657/change-oracle-jdbc-thin-client-identifier/1612688). If that's not feasible, [see this article about finding the PID based on v$session.port](https://suboptimalplan.wordpress.com/2015/03/01/oracle-jdbc-session-and-linux-process/)