# tomcat 7 jdbc connection pool and jdbc4 validation

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, tomcat7, jdbc-pool

I would like to validate a jdbc connection using tomcat 7 jdbc pool using JDBC4 [Connection.isValid](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#isValid(int)) instead of a validation Query.

I am wondering if implementing a [Validator](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/Validator.html) like bellow would be enough. Also I am wondering which would be a nice timeout.

Thanks in advance!
Fede

PS: I am using oracle 11g.

```
public class MyValidator implements Validator{
   public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 5;

   public boolean validate(final Connection c, final int validateAction){
      try{
         return c.isValid(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
      }catch(Exception e){
        // LOG e
        return false;
      }
}
```

Comment: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48817. I cannot tell from the report if this was implemented or not but surely you are not the first one to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

A debugger would help you troubleshoot the situation: Tomcat / DBCP connection pools do not return a raw connection but a wrapper/adapter that recycle underlying "true" connections. The pool usually checks the connections by itself (reconnect if needed) and, I guess, does not allow to really validate.

You have more info about the pool validation parameters in the [Tomcat doc](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html). [Another exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483356/connection-cannot-be-cast-to-oracle-jdbc-oracleconnection) deals about JBoss pools wrapping Oracle connections, what is a common practice.