# How to fix deprecated oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor, oracle.sql.STRUCT and oracle.sql.StructDescriptor

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, deprecated

I use the below JDBC code to call an Oracle stored procedure which takes an Array input.

But the the below three classes are deprecated. How to replace this ?

```
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;
import oracle.sql.STRUCT;
import oracle.sql.StructDescriptor;
```

**Java code**

```
        Object[] reportArray = new Object[3]; 
        STRUCT[] struct = new STRUCT[reports.size()];

        ArrayDescriptor arrayDescriptor = new ArrayDescriptor(new SQLName("T_REPORT_TABLE", (OracleConnection) connection), connection);
        StructDescriptor structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("R_REPORT_OBJECT", connection);

        int arrayIndex = 0;
        for (Report data : reports) {
            reportArray[0] = data.getXXX();
            reportArray[1] = data.getYYY();
            reportArray[2] = data.getZZZ();

            struct[arrayIndex++] = new STRUCT(structDescriptor, connection, reportArray);
        }

        oracle.sql.ARRAY reportsArray = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(arrayDescriptor, connection, struct);
        callableStatement.setArray("T_REPORT_IN", reportsArray);

        callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From oracle API documentation.

**[ArrayDescriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/ArrayDescriptor.html)**

> Use factory method OracleConnection.createOracleArray to create an instance of java.sql.Array directly.

**[STRUCT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/STRUCT.html)**

> Use java.sql.Struct interface for declaration instead of using concrete class oracle.sql.STRUCT.

**[StructDescriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/StructDescriptor.html)**

> Use factory method Connection.createStruct to create an instance of java.sql.Struct directly.

Here are the full list of [Deprecated Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/deprecated-list.html#class) mentioned in the oracle API documentation.

Comment: Ok,that's cute - so how am I supposed to get an instance of `OracleConnection` when I'm working against a `DataSource` instance that may or may not be doing various fancy proxy/wrapping tricks?

Comment: @demaniak casting the generic connection object to oracleconnection should work above java 6

Answer (score 21):

Thanks UUIUI, I now removed the deprecated classes and the fixed code looks as below if anyone needs it later.

```
    Object[] reportArray = new Object[3]; 
    Struct[] struct = new Struct[reports.size()];

    int arrayIndex = 0;
    for (Report data : reports) {
        reportArray[0] = data.getXXX();
        reportArray[1] = data.getYYY();
        reportArray[2] = data.getZZZ();

        struct[arrayIndex++] = connection.createStruct("R_REPORT_OBJECT", reportArray);
    }

    Array reportsArray = ((OracleConnection) connection).createOracleArray("T_REPORT_TABLE", struct);
    callableStatement.setArray("T_REPORT_IN", reportsArray);

    callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: ok, but if you use a connection pool, you cannot just type cast the connection. Then you have to use the unwrap method. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15483625/1436741