# Error with Structs and Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, struct

Getting error with Structs and Arrays handdling list of objects.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.sql.StructDescriptor cannot be cast to oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor
```

Here is the code:

```
List<Commission> commissions = (List<Commission>) parameter;

Struct[] structs = new Struct[commissiones.size()];
for (int index = 0; index < comisions.size(); index++) {
    Object[] params = new Object[9];

    Commission commission = commissions.get(index);

    /* Setting parameters */

    Struct struct = ps.getConnection().createStruct("T_COMMISSION", params);
    structs[index] = struct;
}

Array array = ((OracleConnection)ps.getConnection()).createOracleArray("C_COMMISSION", structs);

ps.setArray(i, array);
```

Edit, adding T_COMMISSION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE GESFIN.T_COMMISSION AS OBJECT (COM_MZN VARCHAR2(3),
                                                      COM_PVP VARCHAR2(8),
                                                      -- ..More params)
/

CREATE TYPE C_COMMISSION AS TABLE OF T_COMMISSION
/
```

Comment: What line is the exception thrown on?

Comment: `Struct struct = ps.getConnection().createStruct("T_COMMISSION", params);
    structs[index] = struct;`

Comment: It would help if you could provide the definition of T_COMMISSION. Is it an ADT or an ARRAY or some other kind of PLSQL collection?

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 0):

[Link to post with the same case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33351512/1762734)

Add

```
Struct[] struct = new Struct[params.size()];
```

Change

```
Struct struct = ps.getConnection().createStruct("T_COMMISSION", params);
```

to

```
struct[index] = ps.getConnection().createStruct("T_COMMISSION", params);
```

Comment: structs array is already there. It should be created again?

Answer (score 0):

try going in a reversed if loop
`for (int index = commision.size(); index > -1; index--) {`

plus you have a typing error, it is commission, not comision... double check your code and getting a plugin/extension/ad-on to check such error.

Best Regards :-)