# connection.createStruct make Strings empty

Tags: java, oracle

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33351512/5707347) issue and sort of successfully sent Collection to Oracle database.

Unfortunately all my String values in Struct array become empty while packing them from Object into Struct.

```
Object[] reportArray = new Object[3]; 
Struct[] struct = new Struct[reports.size()];

int arrayIndex = 0;
for (Report data : reports) {
    reportArray[0] = data.getXXX(); //data return String here and it become empty on createStruct
    reportArray[1] = data.getYYY();
    reportArray[2] = data.getZZZ();

    struct[arrayIndex++] = connection.createStruct("R_REPORT_OBJECT", reportArray);
}

Array reportsArray = ((OracleConnection) connection).createOracleArray("T_REPORT_TABLE", struct);
callableStatement.setArray("T_REPORT_IN", reportsArray);

callableStatement.executeUpdate();
```

So if data getter(getXXX or getYYY or get ZZZ) return number then it’s okay.

But if getter return String then it gets sent as a null to database. I have checked datumArray and data[] bytes is empty. I can see that value is not passing through createStruct correctly.

I tested it on drivers 7-12.1.0.2 and 8-12.2.0.1

db is Oracle 11c or 12c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding orai18n dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>orai18n</artifactId>
  <version>${oracle.jdbc.version}</version>
</dependency>
```