# Execute Oracle stored procedure with ARRAY input paramater

Tags: arrays, spring-boot, java-8, oracle12c, weblogic12c

Since `oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor`, `oracle.sql.STRUCT` and `oracle.sql.StructDescriptor` are deprecated I'm calling an Oracle stored procedure from Java using `java.sql.Array` and `java.sql.Struct`.

I'm using as a reference this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347134/how-to-fix-deprecated-oracle-sql-arraydescriptor-oracle-sql-struct-and-oracle-s)

Here is my code.

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Struct;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;

public CrearRelacionArbolResponseBean crearRelacionArbol(String mensajeTransaccion,
            CrearRelacionArbolRequestBean request) throws DBException {
        DataSource sgaDS;
        CrearRelacionArbolResponseBean objResponse = new CrearRelacionArbolResponseBean();

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
            sgaDS = (DataSource) ctx.lookup(propiedades.sgaJNDI);
            Array relacionArbolArray;

            if (request.getListaRelacion() != null && !request.getListaRelacion().isEmpty()) {
                conn = sgaDS.getConnection();
                Struct[] struct = new Struct[request.getListaRelacion().size()];

                int arrayIndex = 0;
                for (Relacion relacion : request.getListaRelacion()) {
                    SpCrearRelacionArbolSqlInputType relacionArbol = new SpCrearRelacionArbolSqlInputType();
                    relacionArbol.setPI_SIVCN_IDENT_SUCESOR(Integer.valueOf(relacion.getControlSucesor()));
                    relacionArbol.setPI_SIFON_IDENT_SUCESOR(Integer.valueOf(relacion.getFormularioSucesor()));
                    relacionArbol.setPI_SIARN_IDENT_SUCESOR(Integer.valueOf(relacion.getArbolSucesor()));
                    relacionArbol.setPI_SITIN_IDENT_SUCESOR(Integer.valueOf(relacion.getTipificacionSucesor()));
                    relacionArbol.setPI_SIDRC_TIPO_RELACION(relacion.getTipoRelacion());
                    Object[] objects = new Object[] {
                            relacionArbol.getPI_SIVCN_IDENT_SUCESOR(),
                            relacionArbol.getPI_SIFON_IDENT_SUCESOR(),
                            relacionArbol.getPI_SIARN_IDENT_SUCESOR(),
                            relacionArbol.getPI_SITIN_IDENT_SUCESOR(),
                            relacionArbol.getPI_SIDRC_TIPO_RELACION()
                    };
                    struct[arrayIndex++] = conn.createStruct("USRSICES.T_OBJ_SDA", objects);
                }
                relacionArbolArray = ((OracleConnection) conn).createOracleArray("T_TBL_SDA", struct);// Error SQLException

            } else {
                logger.info("Empty List");
                relacionArbolArray = null;
            }

            logger.info(mensajeMetodo + nombreMetodo + " en DB " + propiedades.sgaDB + ", con JNDI = ["
                    + propiedades.sgaJNDI + "]");
            sgaDS.setLoginTimeout(Integer.parseInt(propiedades.timeOutConecMaxTimeCrearRelacionArbol));
            SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(sgaDS).withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                    .withSchemaName(propiedades.sgaDBOwner).withProcedureName(propiedades.spCrearRelacionArbol)
                    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("PI_SIFON_IDENT_PREDECESOR", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                            new SqlParameter("PI_SIVCN_IDENT_PREDECESOR", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                            new SqlParameter("PI_SIARN_IDENTIFICADOR", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                            new SqlParameter("PI_SIDRN_NIVEL", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                            new SqlParameter("PI_LISTA_RELACION", OracleTypes.ARRAY),
                            new SqlParameter("PI_SIGEV_DESCRIPCION", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                            new SqlParameter("PI_SIDRV_USUARIO", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                            new SqlOutParameter("PO_CODERROR", OracleTypes.VARCHAR),
                            new SqlOutParameter("PO_DESCERROR", OracleTypes.VARCHAR));

            jdbcCall.getJdbcTemplate()
                    .setQueryTimeout(Integer.parseInt(propiedades.timeOutExecMaxTimeCrearRelacionArbol));

            SqlParameterSource objParametrosIN = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("PI_SIFON_IDENT_PREDECESOR", request.getIdFormulario())
                    .addValue("PI_SIVCN_IDENT_PREDECESOR", request.getIdPadre())
                    .addValue("PI_SIARN_IDENTIFICADOR", request.getIdArbol())
                    .addValue("PI_SIDRN_NIVEL", request.getNivelPadre())
                    .addValue("PI_LISTA_RELACION", relacionArbolArray)
                    .addValue("PI_SIGEV_DESCRIPCION", request.getEstado())
                    .addValue("PI_SIDRV_USUARIO", request.getUsuario());

            Map<String, Object> resultMap = jdbcCall.execute(objParametrosIN);

            objResponse.setCodigoRespuesta(utilitarios.isNullOrBlankToString(resultMap.get("PO_CODERROR")));
            objResponse.setMensajeRespuesta(utilitarios.isNullOrBlankToString(resultMap.get("PO_DESCERROR")));

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            logger.error(e,e);
            throw new DBException(codError, msjError, e);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    logger.info(mensajeMetodo + "Ocurrio un error al tratar de cerrar la conexion " + e);
                }
            }
        }
        return objResponse;
    }
```

The full exception is as follows

> Fail to convert to internal representation: weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Struct_oracle_sql_STRUCT@28
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Fallo al convertir a representación interna:
>   weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Struct_oracle_sql_STRUCT@28     at
>   oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.toDatum(OracleTypeADT.java:339)     at
>   oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.toDatumArray(OracleTypeADT.java:372)
>     at
>   oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeUPT.toDatumArray(OracleTypeUPT.java:108)
>     at
>   oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.toOracleArray(ArrayDescriptor.java:1321)
>     at oracle.sql.ARRAY.(ARRAY.java:141)

Answer (score 0):

The new approach is to unwrap the `OracleConnection` and use `createOracleArray`.

```
OracleConnection oracleConnection = getJdbcTemplate().getDataSource().getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
Array array = oracleConnection.createOracleArray("REF_TYPE_ARRAY", referralTypeId);

inputParameters.put("itemIds", array);
```

Also see this thread: [How to create an oracle.sql.ARRAY object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878735/how-to-create-an-oracle-sql-array-object/76571542#76571542)