# Cannot unwrap TmesTen datasource JDBC object in JBoss EAP 6

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, timesten

I tried to get a TimesTenDataSource from JNDI loopup on JBoss EAP 6.4. I have the database configured in standalone.xml for timesten. If I use the Standard Jdbc objects i.e, DataSource, Connection, PreparedStatement then it all works. For some reason I want to use TimesTen specific TimesTenDataSource, TimesTenConnection and TimesTenCallableStatement objects from ttjdbc8.jar. this jar file is placed on JBoss modules directory.

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
TimesTenDataSource ds = null;
DataSource ods = (DataSource) ic.lookup(databaseJDNIName);
log.info("Original data source is " + ods);
/*** above line prints -- Original data source is org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource@16174fbf ***/

TimesTenDataSource ds =  ods.unwrap(com.timesten.jdbc.TimesTenDataSource.class);

/** ds is null here **/

TimesTenConnection tconn = ds.getConnection(); // throws null pointer exception
```

As reference to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483356/connection-cannot-be-cast-to-oracle-jdbc-oracleconnection) I call unwrap to get the underlying TimesTen connection.

Debugging above code shows that the WrapperDataSource does not implement getWrappedObject() method which is in the extended class JBossWrapper.

```
/**
 * Get the wrapped object - override in sub-classes
 * @return The object
 * @exception SQLException Thrown if an error occurs
 */
protected Object getWrappedObject() throws SQLException
{
   return null;
}
```

Here is the unwrap method in JbossWrapper class

```
if (iface == null)
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Null interface");

if (iface.isAssignableFrom(getClass()))
   return iface.cast(this);

Object wrapped = unwrapInnerMost(**getWrappedObject()**, iface);
```

Since the getWrappedObject() returns null everything fails.

Also could not directly cast the WrapperDataSource to TimesTenDataSource doing so result in ClassCastException.

Comment: @AlexPoole thanks for editing can you add jboss7.x tag? It requires 1500 reputation that I don't have.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, [that tag already exists](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jboss7.x/info). You can add the tag to this question yourself. You can only have five tags though, so not sure which one you'd remove; if you can only have [tag:jboss] or [tag:jboss7.x] then the more generic one is probably better. Maybe [tab:oracle] can be removed as it's specific to TimesTen?

Comment: I added oracle since timesten follows most oracle concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed the Oracle TimesTen [white paper](https://www.oracle.com/a/tech/docs/wp-timesten-appsrv-1122-2180237.pdf) on Object Relational mappings which has an example for using JBoss EAP 6.2?

I assume that the configuration for EAP 6.4 is similar to that for 6.2.