# setClientIdentifier on oracle Connection from java application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, clientid

how to set **client identifier** to oracle connection from java application. My stack is hibernate 4.3.6 and spring 4.1.0. Transaction are managed by spring with annotation `@Transactional`

My first try does't work

```
    @Autowired
private QueryDslUtil queryDslUtil;

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void test(String kod) {


    Session tmpSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    tmpSession.doWork(connection -> {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("userId", "mito");
        connection.setClientInfo(prop);
    });


    Objects.requireNonNull(kod);
    QOrganizacia source = QOrganizacia.organizacia;
    queryDslUtil.from(source).where(source.kod.eq(kod)).uniqueResult(source);
}
```

my datasource is provided by weblogic server via jndi register or c3po in dev enviroment and I use **oracle driver v 11.2.0.1.0**

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

OraclConnection interface has dedicated method to do this. 
Some time ago it was `setClientIdentifier` but it is deprecated. Now it is `setEndToEndMetrics`. It allows to set up these columns in `v$session`. 
`select MODULE, ACTION , CLIENT_IDENTIFIER from v$session;`

```
      String metric[] = new String[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_STATE_INDEX_MAX];
      metric[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_ACTION_INDEX]   = "I'm ACTION ";
      metric[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_MODULE_INDEX]   = "i'm MODULE";
      metric[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_CLIENTID_INDEX] = "I'm CLIENT_IDENTIFIER";
      ((OracleConnection) connection).setEndToEndMetrics(metric, (short) 0);
```

Comment: thank you, it is working, but Connection cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection in my application. I have proxy connection and that connection have inner OracleConnection, but no public method to get inner Oracle connection. I'm trying this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483356/connection-cannot-be-cast-to-oracle-jdbc-oracleconnection

Comment: There is the way to get the underlying connection. For hibernate these two should work. 
`OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class );`
other option is 
`OracleConnection oracleConnection oc = (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection) connection.getMetaData().getConnection();` 

For jboos 
`Connection c = dataSource.getConnection();
org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection wc = (WrappedConnection) c;
OracleConnection ajc = (OracleConnection ) wc.getUnderlyingConnection();`

Answer (score 0):

solved on weblogic server:

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void log(String kod) {


    Session tmpSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    tmpSession.doWork(connection -> {
        WebLogicNativeJdbcExtractor wlne = new WebLogicNativeJdbcExtractor();
        Connection oracleConnection = wlne.getNativeConnection(connection);
        LOGGER.debug("in work...");
        LOGGER.debug("is oracleConnection {}", oracleConnection instanceof OracleConnection);
        LOGGER.debug("oracleConnection casted {}", oracleConnection);
        String metric[] = new String[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_STATE_INDEX_MAX];
        metric[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_ACTION_INDEX] = "I'm ACTION ";
        metric[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_MODULE_INDEX] = "i'm MODULE";
        metric[OracleConnection.END_TO_END_CLIENTID_INDEX] = "user";
        ((OracleConnection )oracleConnection).setEndToEndMetrics(metric, (short) 0);
    });


    Objects.requireNonNull(kod);
    QOrganizacia source = QOrganizacia.organizacia;
    queryDslUtil.from(source).where(source.nazov.eq(kod)).uniqueResult(source);
}
```