# Why am I getting "format error: Property is 'v$session.program'" connecting to Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, maven, oracle11g

I'm connecting to an Oracle 11g database from a Java application.  I'm getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection property: format error: Property is 'v$session.program' and value is '<My Maven application's name>'
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.validateConnectionProperties(T4CConnection.java:4540)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.readConnectionProperties(PhysicalConnection.java:2345)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:517)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
at oracle.ucp.jdbc.DataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.createConnection(DataSourceConnectionFactoryAdapter.java:100)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is your connection string (excl. password, of course)?

Answer (score 10):

We figured it out.  Our application name was one character too long: it was `49` characters instead of `48` or fewer.

Here's a list of the `v$session` properties and their length limits:

- `v$session.machine`: 64
- `v$session.iname`: no limit
- `v$session.ename`: no limit
- `v$session.process`: 24
- `v$session.program`: 48
- `v$session.terminal`: 30
- `v$session.osuer`: 30

Also, none of the properties can match this regex: `.*[\00\(\)].*`, which I think means no parentheses.

If you are getting the error and want to see the code, just add an exception breakpoint in your IDE for `SQLException`.  You should end up in a class called `T4CConnection.class`.

Here's the decompiled code for the method, `validateConnectionProperties()`:

```
void validateConnectionProperties() throws SQLException {
    super.validateConnectionProperties();
    String var1 = ".*[\\00\\(\\)].*";
    SQLException var2;
    if(this.thinVsessionOsuser == null || !this.thinVsessionOsuser.matches(var1) && this.thinVsessionOsuser.length() <= 30) {
        if(this.thinVsessionTerminal == null || !this.thinVsessionTerminal.matches(var1) && this.thinVsessionTerminal.length() <= 30) {
            if(this.thinVsessionMachine != null && (this.thinVsessionMachine.matches(var1) || this.thinVsessionMachine.length() > 64)) {
                var2 = DatabaseError.createSqlException((OracleConnection)null, 190, "Property is \'v$session.machine\' and value is \'" + this.thinVsessionMachine + "\'");
                var2.fillInStackTrace();
                throw var2;
            } else if(this.thinVsessionProgram == null || !this.thinVsessionProgram.matches(var1) && this.thinVsessionProgram.length() <= 48) {
                if(this.thinVsessionProcess == null || !this.thinVsessionProcess.matches(var1) && this.thinVsessionProcess.length() <= 24) {
                    if(this.thinVsessionIname != null && this.thinVsessionIname.matches(var1)) {
                        var2 = DatabaseError.createSqlException((OracleConnection)null, 190, "Property is \'v$session.iname\' and value is \'" + this.thinVsessionIname + "\'");
                        var2.fillInStackTrace();
                        throw var2;
                    } else if(this.thinVsessionEname != null && this.thinVsessionEname.matches(var1)) {
                        var2 = DatabaseError.createSqlException((OracleConnection)null, 190, "Property is \'v$session.ename\' and value is \'" + this.thinVsessionEname + "\'");
                        var2.fillInStackTrace();
                        throw var2;
                    }
                } else {
                    var2 = DatabaseError.createSqlException((OracleConnection)null, 190, "Property is \'v$session.process\' and value is \'" + this.thinVsessionProcess + "\'");
                    var2.fillInStackTrace();
                    throw var2;
                }
            } else {
                var2 = DatabaseError.createSqlException((OracleConnection)null, 190, "Property is \'v$session.program\' and value is \'" + this.thinVsessionProgram + "\'");
                var2.fillInStackTrace();
                throw var2;
            }
        } else {
            var2 = DatabaseError.createSqlException((OracleConnection)null, 190, "Property is \'v$session.terminal\' and value is \'" + this.thinVsessionTerminal + "\'");
            var2.fillInStackTrace();
            throw var2;
        }
    } else {
        var2 = DatabaseError.createSqlException((OracleConnection)null, 190, "Property is \'v$session.osuser\' and value is \'" + this.thinVsessionOsuser + "\'");
        var2.fillInStackTrace();
        throw var2;
    }
}
```