# JDBC identify api name in the view v$session

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I would like to know how I can identify which api connects to the database since in the view v-4session shows in PROGRAM the JDBC THIN CLIENT record as the image shows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3607M.jpg)

I would like more details of the connection to know which api generates more connections

DB: Oracle 11g

Comment: [This might help?](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_sessio.htm#ARPLS68061)

Comment: Are you asking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548400/how-do-i-make-my-java-application-identify-itself-to-oracle-on-connection?rq=1